# Can a flat array of strings be considered a "Multidimensional String Array"?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Given an array of `$a = array("Hello","World")` and `$a[0]` holds `Hello` and `$a[0][0]` holds value `H`, is it correct to say that `$a` is a "Multidimensional String Array"?

Comment: And `$a[0][0][0][0][0]` is still `H`.  And `$a[0]['foo']['bar']` is still `H` (on < 5.4).  Just because it looks like an array, doesn't mean it is one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `$a` is a 1-dimensional array. Period.

Although strings can be accessed/modified by character using index notation, and are implemented internally as character sequences, PHP strings are not true PHP arrays.

Comment: it has been called [substring access](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) in the past.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it correct to say that $a is now a Multidimensional String Array?

Ask your PHP:

```
foreach($a[0] as $char);
```

and see what does it say.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), so it's not an array.